# Get results based on conditions in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
Orders

ID       User
-----------------
1        Matt
2        Chris
3        John
```

then I have another table

```
Order_Contact

ID      Order_ID        Type                    Timestamp                   
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1       1               Request                 2018-01-01 10:00:00
2       1               Request                 2018-01-01 10:35:00
3       1               Response                2018-01-01 11:00:00
4       1               Request                 2018-01-01 12:00:00
5       2               Request                 2018-01-01 13:00:00
6       2               Response                2018-01-01 14:00:00
```

My goal is to create a query that returns all Orders that have "open" contact requests that have no response. One response is enough to satisfy multiple requests. Requests that have no response at later datetime than the request are "open". How could I achieve this?

In the above scenario I would like to return

```
ID       User
----------------
1        Matt
```

Comment: What is your expected result? And what does "open" mean?

Comment: I edited my question for what I expect based on the table data.

Comment: I edited that I wanted to return another column in addition to Id from Orders table. Sorry for not mentioning it in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this query

```
select
    Orders.ID, Orders.[User]
from (
    select
        *, max([Timestamp]) over (partition by Order_ID) maxDate
    from
        Order_Contact
) t
join Orders on t.Order_ID = Orders.ID
where
    t.maxDate = t.[Timestamp]
    and t.[Type] = 'Request'
```

Updated query due to changes in the question

Comment: Nice! I measured performance of your sql query and Smutje's in larger data set and your query was approx 10% faster. Could you explain what this line 'max([Timestamp]) over (partition by Order_ID) maxDate' does?

Comment: Please look at the result of query with it. It gets max([Timestamp]) for each Order_ID. The logic in both queries are same. max() over () is a windows function that allows you to avoid subqueries. It's well explained here - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/window-functions-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 3):

First, get the latest entry per order:

```
SELECT Type, MAX(ID)
FROM Order_Contact
GROUP BY Order_ID
```

Then, filter the "open" entries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT Type, MAX(ID)
  FROM Order_Contact
  GROUP BY Order_ID
) as max_id
WHERE max_id.Type = 'Request'
```

Edit:

The solution above works for my MySQL-Installation, but the following solution works even using sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92ecd4/12):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Order_Contact
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        FROM Order_Contact
        GROUP BY Order_ID
    )
) as Reduced_Order_Contact
WHERE Reduced_Order_Contact.Type = 'Request'
```

Edit 2:

Towards the extension of the question, adding columns is a simple join:

```
SELECT Orders.ID, Orders.User
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM Order_Contact
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        FROM Order_Contact
        GROUP BY Order_ID
    )
) as Reduced_Order_Contact
INNER JOIN Orders
ON Reduced_Order_Contact.Order_ID = Orders.ID
WHERE Reduced_Order_Contact.Type = 'Request'
```

Comment: Nice one! How about if I wanted to return other columns in the Orders table in addition to ID? (I should had added more columns to the Orders table in the question)